# DCI example at Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, dci

I am looking for some examples at Java in order to better understand what is DCI and how it should be used.

I have found some great DCI example at C++ here http://fulloo.info/Examples/C++Examples/Account1/

If you are not familiar with DCI architecture read about it here http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html or watch some introduction here http://www.tele-task.de/archive/video/flash/16130/ Last link is more about OO weaknesses.

Bonus question: Does DCI is indeed the next paradigm shift?

Comment: What is DCI? full form please..

Comment: @mtk, It is data, context, interaction, for more see http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html

Comment: looks more like an invitation to visit your website, not a real question. voted to close

Comment: @yegor256 alexsmail is not the owner (nor author) of that site. It's managed by Trygve Reenskaug and James O. Coplien (the creators of DCI) and I. The article on artima i Work by Trygve and James. The DCI site (fullOO.info) do at the moment not have any Java examples. For that I do believe this is actually a valid question in regards to some authorative examples in Java

Comment: @mtk have a look at the posted artima article, http://fulloo.info or the book Lean architecture by James O. Coplien and Gertrud Bjornvig

Comment: Take a look at [Apache Zest](https://zest.apache.org/)